# How to enable PodSecurityPolicy in kong gateway?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kong, podsecuritypolicy

everyone,

I was trying to learn about Kong Gateway and its working. I installed Helm in a GKE cluster with version 1.27, but I couldn’t enable the PodSecurity Policy in values.yaml and upgrade the Helm. The error was

(Error: UPGRADE FAILED: execution error at (kong/templates/psp.yaml:2:15): Cluster doesn’t have policy/v1beta1 API.)

Can anyone help me with it?

Thank you!

[changed podsecurity policy to true in helm chart of kong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWv86.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pirDV.png)

I tried to install the kong with pod security enable in gke clusster 1.27 i got this error
can anyone help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PodSecurityPolicy has been deprecated with Kubernetes 1.21

> Kubernetes 1.21 starts the deprecation process for PodSecurityPolicy.

and has been removed with Kubernetes 1.25

> With the release of Kubernetes v1.25, PodSecurityPolicy has been removed.

Since your try to install on 1.27 you can't configure PodSecurityPolicy in the chart. You sould first check if your chart is outdated and update it.

[Read more](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/04/06/podsecuritypolicy-deprecation-past-present-and-future/) about the topic here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
If the PodSecurity Policy has been removed, what would be the next alternative for me to consider?

Comment: That depends on what is configured in your cluster to take care of that. Default should be [pod security standard](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-standards/), but it could also be kyverno or gatekeeper. Please consider voting/accepting the answer if it was helpful